# copy customer fields to shipping info field private void btn_Click c#

Tags: c#, .net

i have a form created using Visual Basic 2008 in c#
i want to add a button that when clicked, it will check multiple fields which if contains text then paste it into other text boxes if they are empty
this is the code i currently have, but its not working

```
 private void btnCopytoBAN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (BAddress.Text.Length < 0)
        {BAddress.Text = MAddress.Text;}
        else
        if (BCity.Text.Length < 0)
        {BCity.Text = MCity.Text;}
        else
        if (BState.Text.Length < 0)
        {BState.Text = MState.Text;}
        else
        if (BZIP.Text.Length < 0)
        {BZIP.Text = MZIP.Text;}
        else
        if (BEmail.Text.Length < 0)
        {BEmail.Text = MEmail.Text;}
        else
        if (BName.Text.Length < 0)
        {BName.Text = MFName.Text + " " + MLName.Text;}
        else
        if (TEmail.Text.Length < 0)
        {TEmail.Text = MEmail.Text;}
        else
        if (TName.Text.Length < 0)
        {TName.Text = MFName.Text + " " + MLName.Text;}
        else
        if (MWork.Text.Length < 0)

        if (MWork.Text.Length > 0)
        {BPhone.Text = MWork.Text;
         TPhone.Text = MWork.Text; ;
        }
        else if (MMobile.Text.Length > 0)
        {BPhone.Text = MMobile.Text;
         TPhone.Text = MMobile.Text; ;}
        else if (MHome.Text.Length > 0)
        {BPhone.Text = MHome.Text;
         TPhone.Text = MHome.Text; ;}
    }
```

Comment: i have several fields (address, home phone, mobile phone, work phone, email, etc) for the "Customer"
i also almost all the same fields under "Billing" and i want that  "if" some of the "Billing" Fields are empty, then take the info from "Customer" and fill it into the "Billing" field.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thanks everyone for their help, this is the code i am now using which works perfect.

```
     private void btnCopytoBAN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (BAddress.Text.Length == 0)
            BAddress.Text = MAddress.Text;

        if (BCity.Text.Length == 0)
            BCity.Text = MCity.Text;

        if (BState.Text.Length == 0)
            BState.Text = MState.Text;

        if (BZIP.Text.Length == 0)
            BZIP.Text = MZIP.Text;

        if (BEmail.Text.Length == 0)
            BEmail.Text = MEmail.Text;

        if (BName.Text.Length == 0)
            BName.Text = MFName.Text + " " + MLName.Text;

        if (TEmail.Text.Length == 0)
            TEmail.Text = MEmail.Text;

        if (TName.Text.Length == 0)
            TName.Text = MFName.Text + " " + MLName.Text;

        if (BPhone.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            BPhone.Text = MWork.Text;
            if (BPhone.Text.Length == 0)
                BPhone.Text = MMobile.Text;
            if (BPhone.Text.Length == 0)
                BPhone.Text = MHome.Text;
        }

        if (TPhone.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            TPhone.Text = MWork.Text;
            if (TPhone.Text.Length == 0)
                TPhone.Text = MMobile.Text;
            if (TPhone.Text.Length == 0)
                TPhone.Text = MHome.Text;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The other answer is really useful. You should accept that question, instead of posting the similar code.

Answer (score 2):

Text.Length cannot be less than 0, it can be 0 if the Text is empty. I think that's the issue in your code.

You can use [String.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) instead of Text.Length as below.

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(BAddress.Text)) //(BAddress.Text.Length < 0)
{
    BAddress.Text = MAddress.Text;
}
```

I am confuse with your if-else statements, make sure you do that correctly. You are not specific about your issue. Should your if-else looks like below? Do you really need else clauses?

```
if (BAddress.Text.Length = 0)
{BAddress.Text = MAddress.Text;}

if (BCity.Text.Length = 0)
{BCity.Text = MCity.Text;}

if (BState.Text.Length = 0)
{BState.Text = MState.Text;}

if (BZIP.Text.Length = 0)
{BZIP.Text = MZIP.Text;}
```

...............

```
if (MWork.Text.Length > 0)
{BPhone.Text = MWork.Text;
 TPhone.Text = MWork.Text;}
if (MMobile.Text.Length > 0)
{BPhone.Text = MMobile.Text;
 TPhone.Text = MMobile.Text;}
if (MHome.Text.Length > 0)
{BPhone.Text = MHome.Text;
 TPhone.Text = MHome.Text;}
```

Comment: The Text property is never null, testing for Text.Length == 0 is best.  But close enough.

Comment: @HansPassant: That's a good point. In that way IsNullOrEmpty can be a little overhead. Thanks!

Comment: i got it working
but i am still having a problem with the (MMobile, MWork, MHome) fields, what i want to do there is take the MMobile and paste it into the BPhone and TPhone, but if MMObile is empty then use MWork, if MWOrk is empty then use MHome


i got it working by doing the following:
but i am still having a problem with the (MMobile, MWork, MHome) fields, what i want to do there is take the MMobile and paste it into the BPhone and TPhone, but if MMObile is empty then use MWork, if MWOrk is empty then use MHome

Comment: @lzzy G: See my edit. I think you don't want 'else' clause. You have to understand the purpose of 'if', 'else' and 'else if'.